# UnitStep in Mathematica when t varies differently

Tags: homework

How can I use the `UnitStep` command when I have a piecewise function $f(t)$, where $f(t)= 0$, when $|t|>4$, and $f(t)=1$, when $|t|<4$? I tried with `UnitStep[t-4]` but didn't work like I want it to work.

Comment: Welcome to _Mathematica_.SE. Please clarify your question. Are you trying to define `f[t]` in _Mathematica_? Have you looked at [Piecewise](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Piecewise.html) in the Documentation Center?

Comment: Yes, my teacher asked me to define this f(t) using the UnitStep command

Comment: Anyone have a suggestion for a better tag than mathematical-optimization?

Comment: Sorry about it, I never used this website before, I just put the first thing that I found.

Comment: Why did you leave out the `Abs`? Use `Plot[UnitStep[4 - Abs[t]], {t, -6, 6}]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
f[t_] := UnitStep[t + 4] - UnitStep[t - 4]
Plot[f[t], {t, -10, 10}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can use this like this also:

```
Plot[Sin[t] f[t], {t, -10, 10}, Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Plot[5 f[t], {t, -10, 10}, Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

etc...

Comment: A piss wise master :)

Comment: Thank u, I was trying to plug with Abs(t), but it was not working. I never used Mathematica before take this class, I am learning now =)